# How to include external css and javascript file inside twig view in slim framework

Tags: javascript, php, twig, slim

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

it is not including these two files in my twig template can anyone help how
to include external css/js file inside twig template.(this is my twig template)

Comment: where do you store these files?

Comment: Both the css and js files are stored inside view folder inside public directory and twig template is aslo located in the same view folder

Comment: Why do you place those assets in your view folder?

Comment: Because view is the directory pointing to twig template

Comment: Just use `href="{{ base_url() }}/path/to/file.css"`

Comment: It is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

- set your app's base in the `.htaccess` to your public folder where you'd usually put all your `css`, `js`, `media`
- call your css file from the base using `href="{{ base_url() }}/css/main.css"`

Comment: How can i set the base path in. htaccess file can you show me

Comment: Add this to your  `.htaccess`:
`RewriteBase /YOURAPP/PATH/TO/YOUR/PUBLIC/FOLDER/public/`

Comment: Ok, but what if i had my assets file outside of public directory inside another folder then how can i include those assets file. it is not working when i have my assets file outside of public directory

Comment: then you try to find the path from the public directory to your assets file. `href="{{ base_url() }}/../css/main.css"`